# id()s of bound and unbound method objects --- sometimes the same for different objects, sometimes different for the same object

Tags: python, object, methods

I've tried some code about bound and unbound methods. When we call them, I think both of them would return objects. But when I use `id()` for getting some information, it returns something I don't understand.

IDE: Eclipse

Plugin: pydev

```
Class C(object):
    def foo(self):
        pass

cobj = C()

print id(C.foo)    #1
print id(cobj.foo) #2

a = C.foo
b = cobj.foo

print id(a)        #3
print id(b)        #4
```

And the output is...

```
5671672

5671672

5671672

5669368
```

Why do #1 and #2 return the same id? Aren't they different objects? And if we assign `C.foo` and `conj.foo` to two variables, #3 and #4 return the different id.

I think #3 and #4 show that they are not the same object, but #1 and #2...

What is the difference between the id of bound method, and an unbound method?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Whenever you look up a method via `instance.name` (and in Python 2, `class.name`), the method object is created a-new. Python uses the [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) to wrap the function in a method object each time.

So, when you look up `id(C.foo)`, a new method object is created, you retrieve its id (a memory address), then *discard the method object again*. Then you look up `id(cobj.foo)`, a new method object created that re-uses the now freed memory address and you see the same value. The method is then, again, discarded (garbage collected as the reference count drops to 0).

Next, you stored a reference to the `C.foo` unbound method in a variable. Now the memory address is not freed (the reference count is 1, instead of 0), and you create a *second* method instance by looking up `cobj.foo` which has to use a new memory location. Thus you get two different values.

See the [documentation for `id()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id):

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. ***Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same `id()` value***.
>
> **CPython implementation detail**: This is the address of the object in memory.

Emphasis mine.

You can re-create a method using a direct reference to the function via the `__dict__` attribute of the class, then calling the [`__get__` descriptor method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__):

```
>>> class C(object):
...     def foo(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> C.foo
<unbound method C.foo>
>>> C.__dict__['foo']
<function foo at 0x1088cc488>
>>> C.__dict__['foo'].__get__(None, C)
<unbound method C.foo>
>>> C.__dict__['foo'].__get__(C(), C)
<bound method C.foo of <__main__.C object at 0x1088d6f90>>
```

Note that in Python 3, the whole unbound / bound method distinction has been dropped; you get a function where before you'd get an unbound method, and a method otherwise, where a method is *always* bound:

```
>>> C.foo
<function C.foo at 0x10bc48dd0>
>>> C.foo.__get__(None, C)
<function C.foo at 0x10bc48dd0>
>>> C.foo.__get__(C(), C)
<bound method C.foo of <__main__.C object at 0x10bc65150>>
```

Furthermore, Python 3.7 adds a new [`LOAD_METHOD`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_METHOD) - [`CALL_METHOD`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_METHOD) opcode pair that replaces the current `LOAD_ATTRIBUTE` - `CALL_FUNCTION` opcode pair precisely to avoid creating a new method object each time. This optimisation transforms the executon path for `instance.foo()` from `type(instance).__dict__['foo'].__get__(instance, type(instance))()` with `type(instance).__dict__['foo'](instance)`, so 'manually' passing in the instance directly to the function object.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: It's an implementation detail of CPython; other python implementations probably use a different value for `id()`.

Comment: Possibly nicer on the eyes: `MethodType(vars(C)['foo'], C(), C)`. But it's not as if code like this should be commonplace.

Comment: @eryksun: My point was to illustrate *how* python creates the method in the first place; to show that it is not created once for a class then retrieved each time. Using `types.MethodType()` would defeat that purpose.

Comment: I appreciate that and upvoted your answer. I was just offering up an alternative to directly using the special attributes.

Comment: @eryksun: Sure; still, I'd probably still use `__get__` myself to bind a function to an instance (e.g. `func.__get__(instance, type(instance))`); to me personally that documents the purpose quite well.

Comment: I never knew method 'objects' are created every time they are called. Is there any advantage to this technique? Why not keeping them in the object's dict?

Comment: @Vinny: because Python is highly dynamic. `instance.method()` can result to a completely different function object from one call to the next.

Comment: @Vinny: Python 3.7 does now avoid actually creating the method object in the most common cases thanks to [two new bytecodes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365920/unable-to-recover-account-after-suspension-period); this applies when there is an attribute lookup with a call directly following in the same expression. I already cover that in my answer here.

Comment: @TomKarzes yes, which is why I stated that in my answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah ok, I hadn't read far enough.  I had encountered this in Python 3, when I saw that `id(cobj.foo) == id(cobj.foo)`.  But this was because the object created by `cobj.foo` was being freed after being passed to the first `id` call, then the same `id` was being reused by the second `cobj.foo` before it was passed to the second `id` call.  If the bound methods are both live, this doesn't happen, e.g. `m1 = cobj.foo; m2 = cobj.foo; id(m1) == id(m2)` is guaranteed to be `False`.

Comment: @TomKarzes yes, I cover those aspects in my answers on [string interning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24245514), and [how unique the `id()` value is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52181584).

Answer (score 11):

Adding to @Martijn Pieters's very good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13348193/846892):

```
In [1]: class C(object):
   ...:     def foo(self):
   ...:         pass
   ...:

In [2]: c = C()

In [3]: id(c.foo), id(C.foo)
Out[3]: (149751844, 149751844)  # so 149751844 is current free memory address

In [4]: a = c.foo  # now 149751844 is assigned to a

In [5]: id(a)              
Out[5]: 149751844

# now python will allocate some different address to c.foo and C.foo     

In [6]: id(c.foo), id(C.foo)    # different address used this time, and
Out[6]: (149752284, 149752284)  # that address is freed after this step

# now 149752284 is again free, as it was not allocated to any variable

In [7]: b = C.foo  # now 149752284 is allocated to b    

In [8]: id(b)
Out[8]: 149752284                

In [9]: c.foo is C.foo  # better use `is` to compare objects, rather than id()
Out[9]: False
```