# Repeatable id clashes on python objects

Tags: python

I understand that the python builtin `id()` returns an ID that is unique for the lifetime of an object. Objects with non-overlapping lifetimes, I understand, can end up with the same ID. However, I am trying to understand this rather confusing behavior:

```
>>> id(matplotlib.image.BboxImage.set_cmap)
4424372944
>>> id(numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray.sum)
4424372944
```

And in fact across multiple interpreter instances, the behavior is repeatable:

```
Mac:~$ python2.7 -c "import matplotlib.image; import numpy; print id(matplotlib.image.BboxImage.set_cmap), id(numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray.sum)"
4343186208 4343186208
Mac:~$ python2.7 -c "import matplotlib.image; import numpy; print id(matplotlib.image.BboxImage.set_cmap), id(numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray.sum)"
4521153312 4521153312
Mac:~$ python2.7 -c "import matplotlib.image; import numpy; print id(matplotlib.image.BboxImage.set_cmap), id(numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray.sum)"
4358591264 4358591264
Mac:~$ python2.7 -c "import matplotlib.image; import numpy; print id(matplotlib.image.BboxImage.set_cmap), id(numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray.sum)"
4389970720 4389970720
```

It appears that `matplotlib.image.BboxImage.set_cmap` and `numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray.sum` always get the same ID as each other, even across different instatiations of the python interpreter.

Now I understand that this is consistent with the docs for `id()` since those two objects are created dynamically when accessed and so will indeed have non-overlapping lifetimes. But why would those two unrelated objects always wind up with the same ID?

(This question is different to [Object methods of same class have same id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727490/object-methods-of-same-class-have-same-id) because here I'm asking why this is repeatable across multiple interpreter instances, rather than simply a spurious id clash on objects with non-overlapping lifetimes.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will be true of *any* instance method, which is the type of both the objects you are testing. Each time you access the descriptor, a new `instancemethod` object is instantiated. Since you aren't saving a reference to the newly created method, it is eligible for garbage collection as soon as `id` returns, and it apparently is being collected before the next call to `id`, so the same memory location can be reused.

This behavior can be seen in another way:

```
>>> x = matplotlib.image.BboxImage.set_cmap
>>> y = matplotlib.image.BboxImage.set_cmap
>>> id(x) == id(y)
False
```

`x` and `y` are references to two distinct objects, since referencing `set_cmap` creates a new `instancemethod` object each time.