# Can someone explain how the source code of staticmethod works in python

Tags: python, decorator, static-methods, python-decorators, python-internals

First of all, I understand how, in general, a decorator work. And I know `@staticmethod` strips off the instance argument in the signature, making

```
class C(object):
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        print 'foo'
C.foo    //<function foo at 0x10efd4050>
C().foo  //<function foo at 0x10efd4050>
```

valid.

However, I don't understand how the sourcec code of `staticmethod` make this happen.

It seems to me that when wrapping method `foo` in `staticmethod`, an instance of `staticmethod` is instantiated, then *some magic* happens, making `C.foo()` legit.

So.. what happen in those *magic*? what did `staticmethod` do?

I'm aware the enormous topics on SO regarding `staticmethods` but none of them addresses my doubts. But maybe I didn't hit the magic keyword. If so, please kindly let me know.

For whoever looking for `staticmethod` source code, please refer to https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Objects/funcobject.c

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A `staticmethod` object is a [*descriptor*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). The magic you are missing is that Python calls the `__get__` method when accessing the object as an attribute on a class or instance.

So accessing the object as `C.foo` results in Python translating that to `C.__dict__['foo'].__get__(None, C)`, while `instance_of_C.foo` becomes `type(instace_of_C).__dict__['foo'].__get__(instance_of_C, type(instance_of_C))`.

The `staticmethod` object is [defined in C code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/funcobject.c#l748), but an equivalent in Python would be:

```
class staticmethod(object):
    def __init__(self, callable):
        self.f = callable
    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        return self.f
    @property
    def __func__(self):
        return self.f
```

where `self.f` is the original wrapped function.

All this is needed because functions are themselves descriptors too; it is the descriptor protocol that gives you method objects (see [python bound and unbound method object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348031/python-bound-and-unbound-method-object) for more details). Since they too have a `__get__` method, without a `staticmethod` object wrapping the function, a `functionobj.__get__` call produces a method object instead, passing in a `self` argument.

There is also a `classmethod`, which uses the second argument to `descriptor.__get__` to bind a function to the class, and then there are `property` objects, which translate binding into a function call directly. See [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work).

Comment: I got the source code from PyCharm IDE.. which I have no idea whether it is the real copy..oops

Comment: @user2829759: PyCharm can't access the actual source code (as it is compiled C code) so it reconstructs a shim for you from introspecting the object.

Comment: @martijinpieters Does it reflect what's happening in the C code?

Comment: @user2829759: My Python code version? Absolutely. The PyCharm reflection cannot show what happens *in the methods*, it can only infer a signature.

Comment: @user2829759: the `__func__` property description is utterly wrong, however. It simply returns the wrapped function (just like the `__get__` method does, basically). The `__getattribute__` and `__new__` methods being there is just confusing matters.

Answer (score 0):

The source code of static method is actually written in C, but you can replicate its behavior with this short snippet:

```
class staticmethod:
  
    def __init__(self, decorated_method):
        self.decorated_method = decorated_method
        
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.decorated_method
```

Here is brief explanation of the above snippet, from this [article](https://www.sicara.ai/blog/re-code-staticmethod-decorator) I wrote: “Methods are descriptors and hence implement the magic method `__get__`. `@staticmethod` is a class decorator, reimplementing `__get__` and making it return a version of the decorated method that has not been bound to the object it belongs to. Hence, the decorated method does not have the implicit argument `self`.” If the notions of **descriptors**, **bound methods** or **class descriptors** are not clear to you, they are explained in the article.