# what is the id of a method in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, python-3.x

What is the meaning of id(method_name) in Python? What does it signify.
I have the following class definition:

```
class myclass:
    a = 2;
    b = 3;
    def mymethod(self):
        self.c = 4;
        self.a = 9;
    def othermethod():
        print("This is other method")
    def someothermethod(self):
        print("Some other method")
```

When i run the following commands see the outputs:

```
id(myclass.mymethod)
Out[26]: 79621928

id(class1.mymethod)
Out[27]: 78755912

id(class2.mymethod)
Out[28]: 78755912

id(myclass.othermethod)
Out[31]: 79634504

id(class1.othermethod)
Out[29]: 78755912

id(class2.othermethod)
Out[30]: 78755912
```

*class.method* is giving different ids for each method. But,

*instance.method* is giving the same value across the instances and across the methods within an instance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13348031/270986

Comment: Thanks a lot Padraic & Mark. I couldn't search the question with the tags of my understanding. That answered my question.