# Python unbound method pit fall. Why new variable initialized with unbound method is not referring the target as expected

Tags: python, class, reference, variable-assignment

Please take a look at code, you will get whole message what I am trying to convey.

```
class Foo:
   def fun(self):
       pass

a = Foo.fun
print "a is Foo.fun: %s" % (a is Foo.fun)

b = a
c = Foo.fun

print "b is c", (b is c)
print "c is Foo.fun", (c is Foo.fun)

def barFun():
   pass

bar = barFun
print "bar is barFun", (bar is barFun)
```

OutPut:

```
a is Foo.fun: False
b is c False
c is Foo.fun False
bar is barFun True
```

Here, why the variable a is not referring Foo.fun. As I know variable assignment is like increasing reference count. i.e, new variable will start pointing the object unlike in language c. 
           So, as we are assigning Foo.fun to var a, a and Foo.fun both should point same object in the memory. But results are unexpected. While 
this assignment works well with normal function.

Here is the code id's of objects are different for unbound method assignment.

```
class Foo:
   def fun(self):
       pass

a = Foo.fun
print "Id of a: %s. Id of Foo.fun: %s" % (id(a), id(Foo.fun))

b = a
c = Foo.fun

print "Id of b: %s. Id of c: %s" % (id(b), id(c))
print "Id of c: %s. Id of  Foo.fun: %s" % (id(c), id(Foo.fun))

def barFun():
   pass

bar = barFun
print "Id of bar: %s. Id of barFun: %s" % (id(bar), id(barFun))
```

OutPut:

```
Id of a: 10155824. Id of Foo.fun: 139916772374320
Id of b: 10155824. Id of c: 139916772374320
Id of c: 139916772374320. Id of  Foo.fun: 10156224
Id of bar: 10741352. Id of barFun: 10741352
```

Comment: This is indeed unusual behavior, but it is at least somewhat [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#id19). My practical recommendation is to not worry about it too much, and write code that doesn't depend heavily on the implementation details of `is` or `id`.

Comment: Because when you access `ClassName.method_name` you get a new unbound method object.

Comment: Recommended reading: [python bound and unbound method object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13348031/953482)

Answer (score 0):

In python 2, `Foo.fun` is what's called an "unbound method." All methods, bound and unbound, are created dynamically every time you call `Foo.fun` or `Foo().fun` so a new method object is created on every call.

In python 3 the idea of "unbound methods" is dropped and `Foo.fun` simply returns a function. In this case, you'll get the behavior you expect. (`Foo().fun` still returns a method object in python 3.)