# the id of a class method is changing

Tags: python, class, methods

The problem is described like the following step:

```
class A():
    def b(self):
        pass
>>> A.b
<unbound method A.b>
>>> id(A.b)
140015897411408
>>> id(A.b)
140015897243552
>>> A.b
<unbound method A.b>
>>> id(A.b)
140015897411408
>>> id(A.b)
140015897243552
>>> id(A.b)
140015897243552
```

As we can see, 
**id(A.b) is 140015897411408 first time and then it changes to 140015897243552 2nd time**
and then A.b is evaluated,and the same thing happens again.

why the id of the method is changing?

Comment: Can't replicate this behaviour in CPython 3.4, however, it does occur in Python 2.7. You should define the Python version that you are using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348031/python-bound-and-unbound-method-object