# Python - class attributes, methods and parameters

Tags: python, class, oop

I am starting to study `class` in python, and am trying to get my head around the concepts of `attributes`, `methods` and `parameters` in `OOP`.

I am working with 3 examples:

---

`example 1`

```
   class Clock(object):
        def __init__(self, time):
        self.time = time
        def print_time(self):
        time = '6:30'
        print self.time
```

with:

```
clock = Clock('5:30')
clock.print_time()
```

It prints `5:30`

---

`example 2`

```
class Clock(object):
    def __init__(self, time):
    self.time = time
    def print_time(self, time):
    print time
```

with:

```
clock = Clock('5:30')
clock.print_time('10:30')
```

It prints `10:30`.

---

`example 3`

```
  class Clock(object):
        def __init__(self, time):
        self.time = time
        def print_time(self):
        print self.time
```

finally, with:

```
boston_clock = Clock('5:30')
paris_clock = boston_clock
paris_clock.time = '10:30'
boston_clock.print_time()
```

It prints `10:30`

could please someone explain me how attributes, methods and parameters are being bound to objects in these examples?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: Your question is rather vague.  Attributes, methods, and parameters are very general concepts.  I think you need to narrow down the area that you need to understand.  Right now it's not even clear that you know what attributes, methods, and parameters are.  It might be good to make your question of the form "I think that blah is a parameter and is being bound to an object in such-and-such line of code, is that correct?"  That way people can see what your existing understanding of the concepts is.

Comment: Yes. As @BrenBarn has already said, you question is very broad as of now. Is there something specific about Python's OOP concepts that is confusing you? Instance variables? attribution look-up? method calls? object creation?

Comment: Try reading this first (the UC Berkeley intro to cs class textbook) about classes: http://composingprograms.com/pages/25-object-oriented-programming.html
Then maybe you might have more specific questions to ask.

Comment: @kbunarjo nice link, will look into it, thanks

Comment: I suspect that you haven't copied the formatting of your code correctly, as most of the example code you've posted won't run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python bound and unbound method object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348031/python-bound-and-unbound-method-object)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question, @leaf. That question is about bound-unbound methods. This is about the general of "methods", "attributes", and "parameters" in OOP languages.

Comment: @PrestonHager That is currently, the best duplicate target I could find. Feel free to post your own.

Comment: You don't need to mark a question as a duplicate if it hasn't been asked before. However, it may need to be closed for a different reason, i.e. "too broad".

Comment: @data_garden You might find this useful: https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/ IMHO, anyone approaching learning classes and OOP thinking should read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link [here](http://composingprograms.com/pages/25-object-oriented-programming.html) can explain more about class attributes/methods/parameters.

However, I do understand how complicated these concepts are, so I will answer your question (although in the future, try to ask a more specific question!).

In example one:

`init` (the initializer) and `print_time` are both class attributes. When you initialize the `clock` variable and pass in the parameter '5:30', it accesses the `init` function and hits the `self.time = time` line of code. Since `time` is accessed using a dot notation, `time` is an INSTANCE attribute (specific to the individual object).

When you call `self.print_time()`, the `time` there is a local variable specific to the function call, therefore the instance attribute is not changed. That is why when you print `self.time` it is still 5:30.

In example two:

In this case, the `init` and `print_time` functions are both class attributes (similar to the example above). The initialization of the `clock` object is the same as above. However, when it calls `print_time`, `time` is a the parameter '10:30', and therefore when we just print `time` (notice we did not use any dot notation), it prints only the local variable of '10:30'.

In example three:

`init` and `print_time` are both class attributes, same as the above two examples. When you initialize the `boston_clock` object, it is similar to both example one and two. Then you assign the name `paris_clock` to the object `boston_block` (notice that `paris_clock` and `boston_clock` are just names pointing to the same object, like how I could have two names). Therefore when we execute the line of code `paris_clock.time = '10:30'`, the INSTANCE attribute of this single object is changed to '10:30'. However, since `boston_clock` is pointing to the same object as `paris_clock`, `boston_clock`'s `time` attribute is also '10:30'.

Answer (score 2):

Attributes are the variables within a class or instance. In something like this the variable `hello` is an attribute of the class `Hi`.

```
class Hi:
  hello = "Hello World!"
```

Methods are functions within the class, so for something like this, function `greet` is a method of the class `Hi`.

```
class Hi:
  def greet(self):
    pass
```

Parameters are input(s) that go into a method. So the string, `"Hello World!"` is a parameter of the method `say` in the class `Hi`.

```
class Hi:
  def say(self, saying):
    print(saying)

Hi().say("Hello World!")
```

There's a nice question on the Software Engineering StackExchange site about OOPL. [Explaining OOP Concepts to a non technical person.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34584/how-to-explain-oop-concepts-to-a-non-technical-person)

Comment: _"could please someone explain me how attributes, methods and parameters are being bound to objects in these examples?"_ - I really don't think your answering that question. Seems more like your beating around the bush to me. No offense.

Comment: @leaf Makes sense, I was just trying to explain how each one works in relation to standard programming. The question at the end of the post may work better for explaining the concepts.

Comment: Yeah, I can see where you are coming from. However, the OP seems thoroughly confused, and could really benefit from a good explanation. alas, I cannot find a suitable answer which answer to his question. mabye I'll post my own.

Comment: @leaf - The OP's question is far too broad and needs something along the lines of a tutorial on OOP.