# In python does the variable name, reference and unique identity(id() function) also take up space in memory?

Tags: python, variables, memory-management

For example

```
x = 5
```

the value 5 is stored in the memory. Does variable name x, reference and unique identity(id() function) are also stored somewhere in memory. How does it work?

Comment: in CPython, the reference *is the id*. But yes, variable names live in a symbol-table somewhere.

Comment: I think this might help[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096582/how-unique-is-pythons-id).

Answer (score 3):

It is an implementation detail.

For CPython (the common one...), actually even the `5` itself doesn't take any additional space! [read here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong) (ints from `-5` to `256` live in a pre-allocated array).

Also in CPython, the identity returned by [`id` is simply the address in memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) of the variable, so it is also doesn't take any additional memory to "save".

As for variable themselves, they most probably do take some space in some symbol table that has to remember their binding.