# Why does the id function in Python return the same value for different integer objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-address

I have a function to retrieve an object in Python using the ctypes module:

```py
import ctypes

def object_at_addr(obj_addr):
    try:
        val = ctypes.cast(obj_addr, ctypes.py_object).value
    except:
        return None
    return val
```

I know that the `id` of an object shows the memory address the object is at (for the most part as far as I've seen with builtins and custom objects). On my terminal shell, I tried this on the number 0 and "recursively" found the `id` of each number to see if it was cyclic in some form. Here is the terminal output:

```py
>>> id(0) # num1
4343595216
>>> id(4343595216) # num2
4344636112
>>> id(4344636112) # num3
4344636112
```

To my surprise, the id of two numbers were the same. However, when I use my function and call `object_at_addr(4344636112)`, it doesn't point to either number, but instead returned a different int value as shown below:

```py
>>> object_at_addr(4344636112)
4411205344
```

How can two different numbers have the same id value? Does the `id` function actually return the memory address for all objects, or is it only for custom objects, or is it just a Python design choice to make the memory address the `id` of an object, but it's different for builtin objects?

Comment: The integer objects `4343595216` and `4344636112` did not exist at the same time (they were eligible for garbage-collection as soon as `id()` returned), so there's absolutely nothing keeping Python from reusing the same memory address for the second one.  (There's also absolutely nothing *requiring* Python to reuse the memory address.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How unique is Python's id()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096582/how-unique-is-pythons-id)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `id` is always the memory address in the CPython implementation. The reason that you saw numbers with the same id here is that memory addresses can be re-used. The id is only guaranteed to be unique *for the lifetime of the object*, and since nothing else was holding a reference to the integer `4343595216` it got deleted immediately after the function call returns. That memory location was freed, and then immediately reused by the integer `4344636112` instance.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) actually mention this explicitly:

> Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same `id()` value.