# Inconsistency in outputs given by Python IDLE (using both Shell and Interactive modes) and Google Colabs

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-idle, objectid

I tried a code regarding the IDs of dictionaries I created in Python, but the same code gives a different output when I run it on IDLE and when I run it on Google Colabs. Could anyone explain this?

What confuses me is the inconsistent output of this line:

`print(f'ID1 == ID2: {id1 == id2}')`

The code I used in IDLE was:

```
print('This is the output in a saved program:')
rec = {"Name": "Python", "Age": "20", "Addr": "NJ", "Country": "USA"}
id1 = id(rec)
print(f'ID1: {id1}')[![enter image description here][1]][1]
del rec
rec = {"Name": "Python", "Age": "20", "Addr": "NJ", "Country": "USA"}
id2 = id(rec) 
print(f'ID2: {id2}')
print(f'ID1 == ID2: {id1 == id2}')
```

The output I get is:

```
This is the output in a saved program:
ID1: 2005032928640
ID2: 2005032928640
ID1 == ID2: True
```

In Google Colab:

```
rec = {"Name": "Python", "Age": "20", "Addr": "NJ", "Country": "USA"}
id1 = id(rec)
print(f'ID1: {id1}')
del rec
rec = {"Name": "Python", "Age": "20", "Addr": "NJ", "Country": "USA"}
id2 = id(rec)
print(f'ID2: {id2}')
print(f'ID1 == ID2: {id1 == id2}')
```

Output:

```
ID1: 132233348202304
ID2: 132233833050560
ID1 == ID2: False
```

Comment: The language does not guarantee the behaviour here. Python **can** reuse the same memory location for the second `rec`, because you deleted the reference to the first one. That's what it did when you ran in IDLE. But the interpreter is not obliged to do this, it's free to assign a different memory location for the second `rec` - as it did when you ran in Colab.

Comment: So @slothrop is there any way to predict which one happens? Or is it random?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's exactly random, but it's indeterminate. You can't rely on whether the address will or won't be reused. What are you trying to use this for? There should be another way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How unique is Python's id()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096582/how-unique-is-pythons-id)

Comment: Your IDLE code has a non-code artifact inserted, so that it does not run.

Comment: Running the correct code in IDLE and Python directly both printed True, so this is not really an IDLE question.